# How do I fix problem with missing arguments in Navigator.Push in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a navigation drawer. I wanted to link a page in the navigation drawer
but i'm getting problem with

The problem is highlighted in at the `Info()` saying that

> 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
> Try adding the missing arguments.dart(not_enough_positional_arguments)

this is my navigation drawer code

```
 ListTile(
                leading:  Icon(Icons.person),
                title: Text('Profile', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: (){
                   Navigator.pop(context); // to close drawer
                   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Info()));
                }
              ),
```

the page referred to this code at page profile.dart

```
class Info extends StatelessWidget{

  final Profile profile;
  Info(this.profile);
```

What argument do that I have to pass at the `Info()` ? I'm new I'm trying to learn this flutter course.

The `profile.dart` page is a page where I display the profile of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined 'Profile' type variable at 'Info' constructor.

```
class Info extends StatelessWidget{

  final Profile profile;
  Info(this.profile);  // Here!!!!
```

So you should pass an argument that type is 'Profile' at below code.

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Info(profile)));
```

Answer (score 1):

First to close the Drawer:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Then to navigate on next page:

```
 Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Info(profile)),
);
```

As you have mentioned in Info screen that your constructor needs profile, so you have to pass that when you are navigating.

Comment: thank you for mentioning this `Navigator.of(context).pop();` out!

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't intend to pass any argument to Info page, just delete profile definition from Info Class. If you defined it in order to use in the dart file where Info is, just define it inside _InfoState class just under Info class.

```
class Info extends StatelessWidget{

  final Profile profile;
  Info(this.profile);
```

This code above means your class Info needs profile as a argument when it being made. So when you make it by navigator.push, it needs a argument which will be put to profile.
Therefore, if you just defined profile to use it inside the other part of the dart file, you should define it inside _InfoState class, not inside Info class.